# I want to hide Spinner functionality in service layer in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a basic bootstrap Spinner.vue component

```js
<template>
    <div class="modal" v-if="start">
          <div class="spinner-border text-info" role="status" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;">
            <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
          </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Spinner',
    props: {
        start: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Since it is a big application I would think that it is not the most efficient way to import this component in every single component/page where there would be spinner at data fetching. And also I would want to pre-fetch data and directly pass it down to a page in vue router like:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    name: RouteNames.XYZ,
    path: '/xyz',
    beforeEnter: async (to) => {
      let data = await Service.getList();
      to.params.list= data.list;
    },
    component: xyzList,
  },
]
```

So it would be very benefitial if in my service wrapper class there would be a showSpinner and hideSpinner methods which can be used in all the data fetcher methods like this Service.getList().
Is there a way to do this? Can I somehow import my Spinner component to this service class js?

If it is possible I would want to implement this functionality without any external spinner library.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most efficient way to do this is add this component to `App.vue`. So it is available as soon as the application is loaded.

Next, your data fetching (Axios I am assuming) has a configuration where you've added request interceptors?

In this interceptor, you can toggle the spinner on and off. Without much code, I can't help further, but that should give you more direction.

Below is a simple example. You will notice that I've imported the store, so you can use that to `commit` a mutation which will show/hide the spinner.

```
import axios from "axios";
import store from "../store";

const Axios = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_API_URL,
});

const addToken = (config: any) => {
    const token = store.getters["Auth/getToken"];
    if (token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
};

Axios.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        // toggle the spinner on here
        addToken(config);
        return config;
    },
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

Axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        // toggle the spinner off here
        return response
    },
    (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);

export default Axios;
```

The router wouldn't have anything to do with what you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: So there is no way to implement this without vuex store? Not that I'm complaining about that I was just wondering if it is possible

Comment: Yes of course, in Vue3 you can just pass a function to the axios config and in Vue2 you can use the EventBus. 

Both are not as good as Vuex though (IMO).